# Creating audit log in using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have created a few tables in sqlalchemy. I want to build an audit log for these tables to capture the history. Whenever a table is updated with values or inserted values, these logs needs to be captured in another audit table. How could I achieve this using sqlalchemy

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-continuum

Comment: SQLAlchemy-Continuum *might* or *might not* be a solution. Could you be more specific in what database tech you're using and whether it should use ORM or Core? The ORM can be supported using SQLAlchemy-Continuum with hooks, and Core can be supported *only with triggers* for which a certain kind of support exists for Continuum on IIRC PostgreSQL only

Comment: I am using MYSQL database. I was able to create and insert data to the mysql tables using SQLAlchemy ORM. So I thought to continue the audit logs with ORM. So you say  triggers are best to do with SQLAlchemy Core on PostgreSQL?

Comment: Maybe is not too automatically but I guess this is related: https://medium.com/@singh.surbhicse/creating-audit-table-to-log-insert-update-and-delete-changes-in-flask-sqlalchemy-f2ca53f7b02f